# Como consigo los datos de varios input que autocomplete a otro

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

Buenas tardes, tengo esta bbdd con 7 tablas. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoGGd.jpg 
En la ultima como podemos observar tengo 4 PK porque es necesaria para poder tener a lo mejor un documento con el mismo nombre pero que tenga diferentes versiones.

El problema es:

Como recojo los datos correctamente para eliminar una fila y no 20 filas a la vez por que solo reconoce una primary key?

Tengo este codigo

```
<?php
require_once 'alumno.entidad7.php';
require_once 'alumno.model7.php';
$alm = new Categoria();
$model = new CategoriaModel();
if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
case 'eliminar':
        $model->Eliminar = array(($_REQUEST['titulo_documento']['num_documento']['version']['revision']));

        header('Location: index7.php');
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Esto seria la parte del php y esto el html en el mismo archivo

```
<?php foreach ($model->Listar() as $r): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('titulo_documento'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('proyecto'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('estado'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('idioma'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('num_documento'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('version'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('revision'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('descripcion'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('fecha'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('subcategoria'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('confidencialidad'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('tipo_documento'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('acro_usuario'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('aprobado_por'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('autorizado_por'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('revisor'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('compania'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('codigo_proyecto'); ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="?action=eliminar&titulo_documento=<?php echo $r->titulo_documento; ?>&num_documento=<?php echo $r->num_documento; ?>
                               &version=<?php echo $r->version; ?>&revision=<?php echo $r->revision; ?>"><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Y en otro archivo vendria a declarar esto otro

```
public function Eliminar($categoria,$categoria1,$categoria2,$categoria3) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo
                ->prepare("DELETE FROM documento WHERE titulo_documento = '?' and num_documento = ? and version = ? and revision = ?");


        $stm->execute(array($categoria,$categoria1,$categoria2,$categoria3));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Tambien tengo problemas para actualizar, pero primero quiero poder eliminar registros y una vez pueda alguien ayudarme intentar arreglar yo la parte de del UPDATE. Muchisimas gracias a todos los que puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

En la línea

```
$model->Eliminar = array(($_REQUEST['titulo_documento']
    ['num_documento']['version']['revision']));
```

estás asignando algo a una functión e intentando acceder a un array cuatridimensional que no es tal. Debería ser:

```
$model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['titulo_documento'], $_REQUEST['num_documento'],
    $_REQUEST['version'], $_REQUEST['revision']);
```

Mi recomendación es que te ahorres quebraderos de cabeza con tanto campo. Crea un campo `id_documento int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` en la tabla y luego añade una regla `UNIQUE (titulo_documento, num_documento, version, revision)`.

A partir de ahí, utiliza para solo el id del documento.

Para generar el HTML:

```
<a href="?action=eliminar&id=<?php echo $r->id_documento; ?>"
    ><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
```

Para eliminar el registro:

```
$stm = $this->pdo
            ->prepare("DELETE FROM documento WHERE id_documento = ?");
$stm->execute(array($id));
```

Mucho más fácil, ¿no?